# Tapping into a React child's componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs

Given a reference to a child (defined from a library I can't override), is there a built-in hook already provided to tap into the child's componentDidUpdate?

If I could define the child, this would be the equivalent of:

```
Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        this.child = React.createRef();
    }

    render() {
        return (<Child ref={this.child});
    }

}

Child extends React.Component {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        this.props.onComponentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that can be (properly) done. If I understand correctly, `componentDidUpdate` in the parent is not being called because the parent is not in fact updated when the child changes. Only the child component and its children `componentDidUpdate` methods should get called.

It's possible to come up with some weird solution (e.g., monkey patching `componentDidUpdate` via that `ref`, handling in the parent and then calling the children handler), but that sounds fragile, and you'd be breaking component encapsulation and making your parent and child component tightly coupled. You may also want to ammend your question to better explain why you need to do that. My experience with React is that if you're trying to do something impossible, it's probably because you're missing something.

Comment: Basically it's a library that probably should have a few `onUpdatedACertainState` callbacks but it's not provided, so I was wondering if I could tap into a general stateUpdated callback instead.

Comment: So unless this library uses some other mechanism to dispatch notifications (e.g., Redux), I think you're out of luck. I assume you want to do something when the child changes the DOM, right? If so, another dirty way to get it done, assuming the parent is wrapping these children, is to monitor the wrapping DOM element in the parent for changes (using something like `MutationObserver`). This will make it very hacky and coupled, but at least all these hacks would be concentrated in code you own and control.